# Htaccess help, $1 being used before its set??? what?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this snippet

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It won't allow me to access a file at website.com/js/main.php
but it will let me access index.php

According to my webhost, $1 is being called before it is set. Any solutions?

I'll accept answers when i get back tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: The link in Gubmo's comment is really useful, but the URL seems to now be: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the rewrite to ignore the things which your condition currently specifies. In that case...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

...should work fine. You'll probably want the QSA on there so that if there's a query string, it's properly handled.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working, it gives me 500 errors now.

Thanks though

Comment: You could try changing it to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)` instead just to be explicit

Answer (score 0):

Your web host is wrong. The [order of ruleset processing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) is:

1. pattern in `RewriteRule` is tested (that will populate the `$N` references with values)
2. associated `RewriteCond` conditions are tested (if present)

Only if the pattern matches the current URL path and the associated condition is fulfilled, the pattern is applied.

So in your case the pattern `(.*)` is tested on the current URL path `js/main.php` (without local prefix `/`). It matches (`$0`=`js/main.php`, `$1`=`js/main.php`) so the three associated conditions are tested in the order they appear:

1. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
2. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
3. `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)`

Assuming that the requested URL path `/js/main.php` does not refer to an existing file or directory, the first conditions are both true. But the third one will evaluate to false as `$1`=`js/main.php` and the pattern `^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)` matches (`^js` branch) `js/main.php`. So the condition is not fulfilled and the rule is not applied.