# .htaccess in subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a subdomain as follows:

http://subdomain.domain.com should load what is really http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/contest/

http://subdomain.domain.com/stepone should load what is really http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/contest/stepone

http://subdomain.domain.com/images/example.jpg should load http://subdomain.domain.com/images/example.jpg as normal.

I've had this all set up and working in a subdirectory on the main domain before but now that I'm trying to do it on a subdomain it's stopped working.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript|email|robots\.txt|test\.php|terms\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php/contest/$1 [L]
```

Please help me!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Are rewrite rules working at all? I.e. do you have `AllowOverride All` or something for virtual hosts, as per:

- http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=481815

Also, take a look this comment by Gumbo on this SO question:

- [Htaccess help, $1 being used before its set??? what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377241/htaccess-help-1-being-used-before-its-set-what/2403284#2403284)

Comment: Yeah, mod_rewrite is on. It also works if I use the following: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/index\.php/contest/$1 [L] but then it just works like a redirect and I end up with the long URLs in the location bar.

Comment: Did you try using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ...` instead of `RewriteCond $1 ...` as per 2nd link?

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal .htaccess file is a good example of mapping /?q=query to /query, but not redirecting things which provide an explicit file/directory match. Here's the relevant snippet from Drupal's .htaccess with ?q= changed to index.php/contest/.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/contest/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you need to restrict the domain so that it doesn't redirect normally but just from the one domain, insert before the `RewriteRule` this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain.domain.com/index\.php/contest/$1 [L, P]
```

Is there any reason I shouldn't use the force proxy like this? (Does it slow things down?)

Thanks for your answers guys.